# Rapidjson android error - assertion “IsString()” failed’

Tags: android, c++, json, cocos2d-x

I am getting response from sever and able to parse the data successfully when i run in ios simulator but when i run on android device app closes with msg “unfortunately app has stopped”

and here is the log of error i get -

```
(22798): Abort message - /Users/mihir/Desktop/test/proj.android/../cocos2d/external/flatbuffers/../json/document.h:1681: const Ch* rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>::GetString() const [with Encoding = rapidjson::UTF8<>; Allocator = rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>; rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>::Ch = char]: assertion "IsString()" failed'
```

Here is my rapidjson parsing code -

```
    if (response->isSucceed()) {
    log("Get success");

    std::vector<char>* buffer = response->getResponseData();
    std::string res;
    res.insert(res.begin(), buffer->begin(), buffer->end());
    log("res: %s", res.c_str());

    rapidjson::Document d;
    d.Parse<0>(res.c_str());
    if(d.IsObject()){


        F = d["F"].GetString();
        W = d["W"].GetString();
        T = d["T"].GetString();
        Fp = d["Fp"].GetString();
        Wp = d["Wp"].GetString();
        Tp = d["Tp"].GetString();

 }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated..Thank you…

And here is my log in android -

```
res: {"F":null,"W":null,"T":null,"Fp":null,"Wp":null,"Tp":null,"msg":"Invalid","sid":null}
```

And in Ios Simulator -

```
res: {"F":"135","W":"1","T":"1","Fp":"1","Wp":"1","Tp":"1","msg":"success","sid":"1nf9ecj3j2nmm2lmamblf27n34"}
```

the same server code is returning success in ios simulator and invalid via android..

I echo $_SESSION['sid'] i set via login in next page, but i receive null in android device but in ios it receives the stored session id, how is that?

Comment: You are printing the res.c_str() to log before parsing it - so add this output to your question.

Comment: i am building using cocos console for android..i do adb logcat and i see only this error and no log messages..How to show log in console? any idea..

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky I have updated with log and more details. Can you please check

Comment: As you see your response has changed and instead of string values like "135" you've got null - this you cannot retrieve using GetString(). So 1st - find a way to check that value isnull or IsString before calling GetString. And second - check your Server side - why the response is different from the working case